# File not found in a very basic project

Tags: java

I dont really understand why but I get file not found when I try to load the properties.
I put a file called `c24.properties` in the resources folder alongside with `application.properties`

```
private static final String PROP = "c24.properties";
    private Properties properties;

    // Constructor
    public KTServices() {
        try {
            properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(PROP)); // FILE NOT FOUND??

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Any help? Why it doesn't find? This is a Spring Boot maven project

PS: I just checked the /target and the c24.properties is in the root folder as expected

Comment: You need to define the fully qualified path of the file along with the file name

Comment: Well if I do `properties.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/" + PROP));` it works but WHY?

Comment: Don't load it using FileInputStream.  Better to use a stream from the classpath via class loader.  A classpath stream will work after you package your app in a JAR or WAR file for deployment; FileInputStream will not.

Comment: Try System.class.getResourceAsStream("/c24.properties")

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in the same directory as the class file, you can use the following:

```
properties.load(KTServices.class.getResourceAsStream(PROP));
```

Any property files that are outside the jar requires a full path to locate successfully.

Comment: try `getResourceAsStream()` - its missing an `r` - just see documentation of [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
 at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
 at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
 at com.impactzero.pt.c24handler.services.KTServices.<init>(KTServices.java:19) ~[classes/:na]

Answer (score 0):

```
Properties appProps = new Properties();

        try {
            appProps.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("app.properties").openStream());
        } catch (IOException var3) {
            this.log.error("properties file  not found", var3.toString());
        }

        return appProps;
```